# How to make Neo4J Enterprise backup work?

Tags: neo4j, backup

I'm trying to remotely back up my Neo4J database for already 2 days and nothing works.

I run

```
sudo neo4j-admin backup --backup-dir=backup --name=graph.db-backup --from=1.1.1.1:1111 --timeout=50m
```

The files start to get saved and then simply erased after a while and there's no backup.

I tried setting up `--pagecache=16M` and `HEAP_SIZE` but it has no effect. Sometime it just stalls sometimes I get an error like this:

```
unexpected error: java.io.IOException: org.neo4j.com.ComException: Channel has been closed
```

The DB I'm backing up is Enterprise 3.3.3 and the one I'm backing up with is 3.5.14

Thank you for any help.

Is this the normal Neo4J behavior?

Comment: In general the neo4j-admin executable you're using for the backup should be from the same Neo4j version as the one you're backing up from. You'll want to double-check the configured backup port in your neo4j.conf. Also review the backup documentation: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.3/backup/perform-backup/. Check in your debug.log and neo4j.log and any backup logs for more detail about what happened here, hard to guess without something to trace in the logs.

Comment: Yes, I did that now with the same version and still have the same problem. It either throws an error or if it completes everything until the end, then miraculously all the files that were created on the disk are erased and the process stalls. The DB is about 40 Gb.

Comment: nothing in the logs? does it work with a smaller test instance?

Comment: Smaller test instance works in the logs there’s no information. Is there settings like max open files or anything else I can try? @MichaelHunger

Comment: To clarify, the instance you're trying to back up is 3.3.3 ?